# Accessing multidimensional array in blade

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, eloquent

Each student has a user (one to one), languages and hobbies (both many to many).

A match is composed by two students (self relationship)

I wan to fill a multidimensional array with the matchId, all the info about the first student and all about the second. I'm populating it array this way:

```
$matches = Match::getMatches($semester->id);
  
foreach ($matches as $m)
    {
         $profiles[] = array(  
            'matchId' =>  $m->matchId,
            'local'   =>  Student::with('user', 'language', 'hobby')->where('user_id', $m->localUserId)->first(),
            'incoming'=>  Student::with('user', 'language', 'hobby')->where('user_id', $m->incomingUserId)->first());
    }
```

Now I want to access that data in a blade template but cannot succeed.

```
{{ $profiles['local'] }}
```

works, but when adding something like

```
{{ $profiles['local']['email'] }}
```

I get nasty errors.

Any hints?

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't currently have a multidimensional array. You are storing an Eloquent database result object in `$profiles['local']`, an instance of the `Student` class.

So you'll need to access it like this:

```
{{ $profiles['local']->email }}
```

Alternatively you could put a `toArray()` at the end when you fetch the student:

```
Student::with(...)->where(...)->first()->toArray(),
```

Now you would have a raw PHP array, and could access it like you originally attempted:

```
{{ $profiles['local']['email'] }}
```

---

Side note: when you don't understand how to navigate something, try using `dd` to inspect it.

```
<?php dd($profiles['local']); ?>
```

That would show you that you have an instance of `Student`, and help you understand how to navigate it.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Worked like a charm!